# Finding javascript code in PDF using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

My goal is to extract and process any JavasSript code that a PDF document might contain. By opening a PDF in editor I can see objects like this:

```
    402 0 obj
<</S/JavaScript/JS(\n\r\n   /* Set day 25 */\r\n    FormRouter_SetCurrentDate\("25"\);\r)>>
endobj
```

I am trying to use Apache PDFBox to accomplish this but so far with no luck.

This line returns an empty list:

```
 jsObj = doc.getObjectsByType(COSName.JAVA_SCRIPT);
```

Can anyone can give me some direction?

Comment: tricky. If you read the PDF specification, you'll see many occurrences where there can be javascript. And processing it depends on user actions, e.g. click on an item, change an item contents, and more. So it isn't done by just collecting all javascript and running it.

Comment: Yes but I just want a way to be able to perform static analysis myself on the JS code. The code it's somewhere in the PDF so I should be able to extract it somehow. For example, it was very easy to extract JS code from /OpenAction if such action exists.

Comment: I think you essentially have to walk the object hierarchy from the document root and inspect all objects that might have JS attached. Some work to do.

Comment: To understand what we mean, download the 2.0 version of PDFDebugger and visit the tree. Do this with different PDFs.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am happy to accept your answer if you post the code that you sent me in the PDFBox support group. I would also appreciate if you can post some sample code on how one could exhaustively look inside all COSString objects in a PDF (I don't understand why I'm finding this API so complex, probably because of my small PDF format knowledge).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tool is based on the PrintFields example in PDFBox. It will show the Javascript fields in forms. I wrote it last year for a guy who had problems with relationship between AcroForm fields (some fields were enabled / disabled depending on the values of other fields). There are still other places where there can be Javascript.

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package pdfboxpageimageextraction;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDAction;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionJavaScript;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDFormFieldAdditionalActions;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDNonTerminalField;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField;

/**
 * This example will take a PDF document and print all the fields from the file.
 *
 * @author Ben Litchfield
 *
 */
public class PrintJavaScriptFields
{

    /**
     * This will print all the fields from the document.
     *
     * @param pdfDocument The PDF to get the fields from.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error getting the fields.
     */
    public void printFields(PDDocument pdfDocument) throws IOException
    {
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();

        //System.out.println(fields.size() + " top-level fields were found on the form");
        for (PDField field : fields)
        {
            processField(field, "|--", field.getPartialName());
        }
    }

    private void processField(PDField field, String sLevel, String sParent) throws IOException
    {
        String partialName = field.getPartialName();

        if (field instanceof PDTerminalField)
        {
            PDTerminalField termField = (PDTerminalField) field;
            PDFormFieldAdditionalActions fieldActions = field.getActions();
            if (fieldActions != null)
            {
                System.out.println(field.getFullyQualifiedName() + ": " + fieldActions.getClass().getSimpleName() + " js field actionS:\n" + fieldActions.getCOSObject());
                printPossibleJS(fieldActions.getK());
                printPossibleJS(fieldActions.getC());
                printPossibleJS(fieldActions.getF());
                printPossibleJS(fieldActions.getV());
            }
            for (PDAnnotationWidget widgetAction : termField.getWidgets())
            {
                PDAction action = widgetAction.getAction();
                if (action instanceof PDActionJavaScript)
                {
                    System.out.println(field.getFullyQualifiedName() + ": " + action.getClass().getSimpleName() + " js widget action:\n" + action.getCOSObject());
                    printPossibleJS(action);
                }
            }
        }

        if (field instanceof PDNonTerminalField)
        {
            if (!sParent.equals(field.getPartialName()))
            {
                if (partialName != null)
                {
                    sParent = sParent + "." + partialName;
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(sLevel + sParent);

            for (PDField child : ((PDNonTerminalField) field).getChildren())
            {
                processField(child, "|  " + sLevel, sParent);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            String fieldValue = field.getValueAsString();
            StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder(sLevel);
            outputString.append(sParent);
            if (partialName != null)
            {
                outputString.append(".").append(partialName);
            }
            outputString.append(" = ").append(fieldValue);
            outputString.append(", type=").append(field.getClass().getName());
            //System.out.println(outputString);
        }
    }

    private void printPossibleJS(PDAction kAction)
    {
        if (kAction instanceof PDActionJavaScript)
        {
            PDActionJavaScript jsAction = (PDActionJavaScript) kAction;
            String jsString = jsAction.getAction();
            if (!jsString.contains("\n"))
            {
                // avoid display problems with netbeans
                jsString = jsString.replaceAll("\r", "\n").replaceAll("\n\n", "\n");
            }
            System.out.println(jsString);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will read a PDF file and print out the form elements. <br />
     * see usage() for commandline
     *
     * @param args command line arguments
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error importing the FDF document.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        PDDocument pdf = null;
        try
        {
            pdf = PDDocument.load(new File("XXXX", "YYYYY.pdf"));
            PrintJavaScriptFields exporter = new PrintJavaScriptFields();
            exporter.printFields(pdf);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pdf != null)
            {
                pdf.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As a bonus, here's code to show all COSString objects:

```
public class ShowAllCOSStrings
{
    static Set<COSString> strings = new HashSet<COSString>();

    static void crawl(COSBase base)
    {
        if (base instanceof COSString)
        {
            strings.add((COSString)base);
            return;
        }
        if (base instanceof COSDictionary)
        {
            COSDictionary dict = (COSDictionary) base;
            for (COSName key : dict.keySet())
            {
                crawl(dict.getDictionaryObject(key));
            }
            return;
        }
        if (base instanceof COSArray)
        {
            COSArray ar = (COSArray) base;

            for (COSBase item : ar)
            {
                crawl(item);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (base instanceof COSNull || 
                base instanceof COSObject || 
                base instanceof COSName || 
                base instanceof COSNumber || 
                base instanceof COSBoolean || 
                base == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("huh? " + base);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("XXX","YYY.pdf"));

        for (COSObject obj : doc.getDocument().getObjects())
        {
            COSBase base = obj.getObject();
            //System.out.println(obj + ": " + base);
            crawl(base);
        }
        System.out.println(strings.size() + " strings:");
        for (COSString s : strings)
        {
            String str = s.getString();
            if (!str.contains("\n"))
            {
                // avoid display problems with netbeans
                str = str.replaceAll("\r", "\n").replaceAll("\n\n", "\n");
            }
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

However Javascript can also be in a stream. See in the PDF spec "Additional entries specific to a rendition action", the JS entry:

> A text string or stream containing a JavaScript script that shall be
>   executed when the action is triggered.

You can change the code above to catch COSStream objects too; COSStream is extended from COSDictionary.

Comment: The structure of a PDF is a bit like in this oscar winning film: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mtluyHcOnk

Comment: If you go to the Javadocs->"Use" for PDAction and look for all examples of "return PDAction", code for those and then extract if instanceof PDActionJavaScript, would that be a good start?  Is the PDFSpec's "rendition action" a PDAction?

Comment: @TimAllison I trust nothing, I would search for "javascript" in the PDFBox source code and in the PDF spec.

Comment: Y, I've done the spec, next stop the source.  Thank you!