# PDFBox javascript extraction

Tags: javascript, pdfbox

I would like to know how if PDFBox library is able to extract javascript from a PDF also in location not specifically reported in the PDF specification, like for example in the metadata fields, and if so, how is it possible to extract all javascript code with this library?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pdfbox allows you to access every object in a pdf file which is referenced by the current cross references, at least in a low-level manner. Thus, you can look at every one of these objects and try to find JavaScript bits. Obviously, though, there is no high level method for that. What is the point in looking for JavaScript in places where it has no effect according to spec after all...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if for example I look there is an object stream which contain an obfuscated javascript code, does PDFBox notifies it? Another  point is, if for example a script calls a specific method of the javascript API for Adobe reader, in order to retrieve dinamically other hidden code, it is sufficient to retrieve the main javascript and then try to execute it dinamically(because in a certain point it should call the appropriate method to do that)? So is there a framework that already implementt Acrobat DOM? @mkl

Comment: *"an object stream which contain an obfuscated javascript code, does PDFBox notifies it"* - pdfbox recognises it as a pdf stream and allows you to retrieve it as such. You have to implement the code recognising that this generic stream contains obfuscated JavaScript.

Comment: I thank you for the suggestions.The problem is that I have made a study of the various malware detection systems making a taxonomy and the problem is that there is some javascript stored also in  metadata item, how can I do to detect this fact? My idea is to run the javascript taken, but how can I do to put all the scripts together, in the right order(because they could be saved in various points of the file), and then run it? Of course then there is the problem that when I run it I must have JavaScript APIs for Adobe(otherwise I have some errors), there is something already implemented?@mkl

Comment: I'm not aware of an open source implementation of the Adobe object model.

Comment: Do you know which is the best implemented parser for PDF documents? And which are the most features used in malicious PDF documents too? Thanks in advance. @mkl

Comment: What does *"best implemented"* mean? Most adherent to the spec? Laxest concerning minor errors in the pdf?smallest memory footprint? Fastest? Some other criteria?

Comment: I'm mainly interested in the one having the best parsing performance, according to the specification. (But if there exist one having a good thradeoff of all the features that you are mentioning is the well came). @mkl

Comment: Maybe here's the answer? It worked for me at least http://stackoverflow.com/a/34899156/706012